# Why is only one of three google fonts loading?

Tags: google-fonts

I added css code to load 3 google fonts, but for some reason only one of them will load, the other two revert to serif/sans-serif. I tried loading them separately (a separate import line for each) as well as combined in one import line. I can't figure out why one will get imported but the other two wont.

This is the import line:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=ABeeZee&family=DM+Serif+Display&family=Prompt:wght@500&display=swap');
```

This is the one that loads:

```
  .paragraph, p {
  font-family: 'abeezee', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto 1.7em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

These are the two that won't load (they won't load in other locations either):

```
h2 {
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  margin: 0 auto .75em;
}

    #nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #131E18;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  font-family: 'DM Serif Display', serif;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all 240ms linear;
      -moz-transition: all 240ms linear;
      -o-transition: all 240ms linear;
      -ms-transition: all 240ms linear;
      transition: all 240ms linear;
}
```

If I replace either with ABeeZee (the font that loads) it loads fine in these locations.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Can you post your code as i have tested the css you posted and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your css and it works fine. Here is how i implemented it. To be able to give you a better answer you should post your code here.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=ABeeZee&family=DM+Serif+Display&family=Prompt:wght@500&display=swap');

.paragraph, p {
  font-family: 'abeezee', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto 1.7em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  margin: 0 auto .75em;
}

#nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #131E18;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  font-family: 'DM Serif Display', serif;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all 240ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 240ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 240ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 240ms linear;
  transition: all 240ms linear;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>TEST AbeeZee</p>
<h2>TEST Prompt</h2>
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a>TEST DM Serif Display</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @ciprian. This is my first time posting here, To clarify, are you asking I post my entire CSS file here, or copy/paste it from the top of it to the point where these lines appear? What's the way to go about it - I see different options. Thank you for your patience and assistance

Comment: @discodisco Put the code from your css file on https://pastebin.com/ and then comment here with the link to it